# how to use pragma

Tags: c++

how to disable structure padding...i am capturing the packets using pacp while displaying i am able to diplay MAC fields properly but unable to display ip fields properly this is because of structure padding...and how to use pragma and some indepth about it, googled but didnt understand properly... i am coding in linux redhat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
// define your structure here
#pragma pack(pop)
```

You can find details about `#pragma pack` and an example [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28VS.80%29.aspx) -- GCC follows the same rules.